# How can I influence the mesh of a character with a garment?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, cloth-simulation

I want to have a garment, previously created in another program and imported into Blender as an *Alembic*, affect and deform the mesh of a character in some places:

Some parts of the tank top and the armband are to influence the body, to simulate a tight fit:

[image]

I think there must be some "magic trick" here, right?

What is the best way to solve this and what possibilities do I have with modifiers in Blender?

---

Reduced to the essential part, one could also take the following example:

Suppose I have a cylinder (the finger) and a torus (the ring), and I want the torus to compress the cylinder.

[image]

[image]

---

**Bonus** *(but I'll probably have to discuss that in more detail in another question, but mention it anyway because it's the same issue, just with animation)*:
Is there a solution/technique that can also work reliably in an animation?

[image]

*Please understand that I can't share this file with the character here, because it has a size of ~30GB including animation...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i don't understand why the master of geometry nodes hasn't the idea to use geometry nodes here...

but here is my proposal:

[image]

You get better results with more subdivisions and you could of course fine tune this with float curves instead of map range (but i think i don't have to tell you that because you know geometry nodes pretty well ;))

here an example with some more subdivisions and smoother step in the map range node:

[image]

I didn't flatten the torus....on the inside...so there is still room for improvement ;)

Comment: "master of geometry" ...coming from you, that's special praise! ;-) But I'm still not sure if I can use GNs in this specific case (The character and the garment). But your answer definitely solves the simplified example, +1 for that ...I'm looking into this more, and still looking for a solution that might work with modifiers for such a complex mesh. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback to your answer. You're right, I can't find a better solution for this task either, although I'm not entirely happy about it. It actually works quite well for simple shapes, but complex meshes can be quite tricky. Anyway: answer accepted as solution! Thanks!